# Python работа с PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

У меня был код, сохраненный в блокноте (.txt). Как только я перенес его в пайчарм и запустил программу - все заработало. Однако, после того как я удалил символ и вернул его назад - вся программа пишет ошибку. Но если я снова вставляю код и не трогаю его, он продолжает работать. Почему? Как такое возможно?

```
oldlist = [10,75,43,15,25,-4,27]
def bubble_sort(mylist:list):
    last_item = len(mylist)-1
        for z in range (0,last_item):
            for x in range (0,last_item-z):
                print (mylist)
                if mylist[x]>mylist[x+1]:
                    mylist[x],mylist[x+1]=mylist[x+1],mylist[x]
print(bubble_sort(oldlist))
```

Comment: Какой символ удаляете? Покажите текст ошибки? Я думаю, что в вашем коде перед блоком `for z in range` отступа быть не должно, у вас в пайчарме тоже отступ в этом месте?

Answer (score 1):

Отступ лишний перед первым `for`

```
oldlist = [10,75,43,15,25,-4,27]
def bubble_sort(mylist:list):
    last_item = len(mylist)-1
    for z in range (0,last_item):
        for x in range (0,last_item-z):
            print (mylist)
            if mylist[x]>mylist[x+1]:
                mylist[x],mylist[x+1]=mylist[x+1],mylist[x]

bubble_sort(oldlist)
```